# order of the commutator subgroup divides $n^{n\left \lfloor \log_2 n \right \rfloor-n+2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $Z(G)$ be its center.

How can I prove the following:

If $(G:Z(G)) = n$ then $|G'|$ divides $n^{n\left \lfloor \log_2 n \right \rfloor-n+2}$.

I can prove that $(G')^n = 1$ and $|G'|<\infty$...

Comment: What is G'? Is it G/Z(G)?

Comment: Also, what's the question?

Comment: @AlexMeiburg $G' = \left \langle g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}g_1g_2\ |\ g_1,g_2\in G \right \rangle$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$. The question is how can I prove this statement?

Comment: Then why don't you edit the question and make it clear what you are asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|G/Z(G)| = n$, it can be generated by $d$ elements $g_1Z(G),\ldots,g_dZ(G)$, where $d \le \log_2 n$.

Let $H = \langle g_1,\ldots,g_d \rangle$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g_1,\ldots,g_d$. Then $G' \le H$ and $|H/Z(G) \cap H| = |HZ(G)/Z(G)| = |G/Z(G)| = n$. So, by Schreier's Theorem, $Z(G) \cap H$ can be generated by at most $nd-n+1$ elements.

Hence $Z(G) \cap H \cap G' = Z(G) \cap G'$ can be generated by at most $nd-n+1$ elements, and, since $(G')^n=1$, $Z(G) \cap G'$ is a quotient of the direct product of $nd-n+1$ copies of a cyclic group of order $n$, and hence $|Z(G) \cap G'|$ divides $n^{nd-n+1}$.

The result now follows since $|G'/Z(G) \cap G'| = |G'Z(G)/Z(G)|$ divides $n$.

Comment: I had the eatimates $|Z(G) \cap G'| \le n^{nd-n+1}$ and $|G'/Z(G) \cap G'| \le n$, but I do not understand why $|G'|$ divides $n^{nd-n+2}$ (it is clear for me that $|G'| \le n^{nd-n+2}$).

Comment: But you can immediately replace all of the statements in the above argument of the form $a\le b$ be $a$ divides $b$. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I forgot to use the fact that $Z(G)$ is abelian... Thank you for your patience!